# App crashes on mobile device after using ProGuard

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

After successfully using ProGuard on my application, it crashes on the startup on my mobile device. 
I use standard configuration of proguard: `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`

And logcat says something like this: `E/AndroidRuntime(13441): at packagename.q.doInBackground(Unknown Source)`

And then some App crashed errors etc.

Why does it not find my Source in doInBackground? Its a simple AsyncTask.
Can anyone help me?

Edit: whole log:

`I/ActivityManager( 1604): Start proc myPackageName for activity myPackageName/.MainActivity: pid=13961 uid=10147 gids={3003}
I/ActivityManager( 1604): Displayed myPackageName/.MainActivity: +744ms (total +1m41s749ms)
E/AndroidRuntime(13961):    at myPackageName.q.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
E/EmbeddedLogger( 1604): App crashed! Process: myPackageName
E/EmbeddedLogger( 1604): App crashed! Package: myPackageName v4 (1.2.1)
E/EmbeddedLogger( 1604): Application Label: XxX
W/ActivityManager( 1604):   Force finishing activity myPackageName/.MainActivity
E/WindowManager(13961): Activity myPackageName.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40dcbed8 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(13961): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity myPackageName.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40dcbed8 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(13961):     at myPackageName.MainActivity.b(Unknown Source)
E/WindowManager(13961):     at myPackageName.l.a(Unknown Source)
I/ActivityManager( 1604): Process myPackageName (pid 13961) has died.`

Comment: This is because of wrong configuartion of Proguard. is pagename is non Component class? If yes use keep for this class. Put the complete log message

Comment: Ouh sry this should be packagename, it shows the name of my package^^ Mhm how to provide the whole log from mobile phone to here :o

Comment: :) q is an Activity class? If yes modify your settings

Comment: Mhm my Activityclasses are named: MainActivity, and Login :o But the doInBackground is in another class, which change some things on the MainActivity, is this the mistake? I think q is because of shrinking etc. of PG, what should I modify? I don't know much about configure ProGuard :/

Comment: Thats why I was asking.. If that was an Activity name not changed by Proguard. use `-keep class pkg.classname { *; }`.

Comment: mhm now it doesnt says `at pkg.q.doInbackground(Unknown Source)`. Instead of `q` it says my real class name but I still get this error of Unknown Source :/

Comment: add `-keep class pkgname.classname.A$*` where A is class name of AsynTask

Comment: Doesn't work :/ Now it says `at pkg.q.doInbackground(Unknown Source)` again

Comment: what is you class name? put your package name and fully qulified name of asynctask class?

Comment: yes I did `-keep class mypkg.nameofasyncclass$*` right?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. The problem was that I'm using jsoup in this `doInBackground`
just added

`#Keep jsoup
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}`

to the configuration and it works well, thanks for all your help